# Android Volley returning null response

Tags: java, android, spring-boot, android-volley

I’ve been using Volley for a while, but lately I’ve been experiencing an error. I’ve tried a lot of the answers provided in other questions, but I have not been lucky yet.

In my project I have an Android app and a backend server. All the calls seem to work fine until I get to this one:

```
    private void getUserData() {
    APICommunicator apiCommunicator = new APICommunicator();
    Response.Listener responseListener = new Response.Listener<CustomRequest.CustomResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(CustomRequest.CustomResponse response) {
            //do something

        }
    };
    Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                errorTreatment(error.networkResponse.statusCode);

        }
    };
    String email = SharedPreferencesManager.INSTANCE.read(getApplicationContext(), "user_email");
    Context applicationContext = this;
    Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
    apiCommunicator.getRequest(applicationContext, URL + "/" + email, responseListener, errorListener, params);
}
```

This call is placed in the `onCreate()` method from the `Activity` accessed just after the login, so the email from the `SharedPreferences` is not `null` (already checked). The problem is that, from time to time, normally after I've pushed a new version of the backend code to the server, the call returns a `NullPointerException`. This happens in the `errorTreatment(error.networkResponse.statusCode)`; line and I know that this will be solved try/catching this access, but the thing I don’t understand is why am I receiving this error when the server is working fine (via postgres). Usually the problem gets solved without me doing anything, just waiting some time (maybe lunch break).

I also checked if it was the server who was deciding, for no apparent reason, to not respond these petitions, but the problem is that the server is not receiving any, so I am suspecting then that the problem is in my Android code.

The code of the `APICommunicator`:

```
    class APICommunicator {

    private static final String API_URL = BuildConfig.API_ENDPOINT;
    private static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    private static final String CHARSET = "utf-8";


    void getRequest(Context context, String url, Response.Listener responseListener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener, final Map<String, Object> params) {
        doRequest(context, Request.Method.GET, url, responseListener, errorListener, params);
    }



    private void doRequest(final Context context, final int method, final String url, final Response.Listener responseListener, final Response.ErrorListener errorListener, final Map<String, Object> params) {
        CustomRequest request = new CustomRequest(method, API_URL + url, responseListener, errorListener) {
            @Override
            public byte[] getBody() {
                try {
                    return new JSONObject(params).toString().getBytes(CHARSET);
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
                Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
                String token = SharedPreferencesManager.INSTANCE.read(context, "token");
                if (token != null) headers.put("Authorization", token);
                return headers;
            }

            @Override
            public String getBodyContentType() {
                return CONTENT_TYPE;
            }
        };
        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                10000,
                3,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(request);
    }
}
```

Hope you can help me.

**EDIT:** The stacktrace log is the following

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.JoanSanchez.project, PID: 13258
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int com.android.volley.NetworkResponse.statusCode' on a null object reference
    at com.JoanSanchez.project.InsideActivity$3.onErrorResponse(InsideActivity.java:190)
    at com.android.volley.Request.deliverError(Request.java:617)
    at com.android.volley.ExecutorDelivery$ResponseDeliveryRunnable.run(ExecutorDelivery.java:104)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Line 190 is`errorTreatment(error.networkResponse.statusCode);`

Comment: Can you share stacktrace  log  ?

Comment: Done, added to the question

Comment: error.networkResponse can be null for some VolleyError . Did you check which error you are getting. Is it NoConnectionError?

Comment: It returns no error. After the defined timeout expires the `Response.ErrorListener` is called, but with a null VolleyError. It looks like Volley has not been able to perform the request, because the server do not receive any. The interesting thing is that 90-95% of the time this call works fine.

Comment: maybe you can override parseNetworkResponse method in the Request class and try to debug this method for the statuscode